# Angular AuthGuard CanActivate not called when signing out - Firebase Auth

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

The AuthGuard CanActivate is called correctly after login and the user is redirected to route they came from. The issue only arises when the user signs out, the CanActivate doesn't seem to be triggered

AuthGuard

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkLogin(state.url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated.pipe(
      tap(auth => (!auth ? this.router.navigate(['login']) : true))
    );
  }
}
```

AuthService

```
  get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(authState => !!authState)
    );
  }
```

app routes

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "dashboard", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: "trades", component: TradeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

adding that.router.navigate(['login']) to logout() works but this feels like a hack as AuthGuard isn't triggered.

```
  logout(): void {
    var that = this;
    this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut().then(function() {
      localStorage.clear();
      that.router.navigate(['login']);
    });
  }
```

One thing I can think of is that this.angularFireAuth.authState is not changed on logout and therefore doesn't trigger the AuthGuard. Meaning if I had isAuthenticated() return a simple boolean which set to false during logout, the AuthGuard would trigger

Comment: As the name suggests, it works on `[Activate]`, not on `[deActivate]`. If you want on deactivate, you need to put a `[CanDeactivate]` guard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove **take(1)** from:

```
return this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(authState => !!authState)
);
```

With **take(1)** you will receive data from observable only once (when you log in).

Comment: I tried both with take(1) and without, it doesn't help. I added the take(1) because someone suggested the observable needs to end for the AuthGuard to work otherwise it will be stuck listening to it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see that you added you guard to providers array in `AppModule`, and this may solve your problem.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'dashboard', 
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate:[AuthGuard],
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
class AppModule {}
```